# deletar uma chave do banco do Django

Tags: django

Quando deleto essa coluna da tabela, o Django me mostra um erro, pelo que entendi essa chave fica armazenada no banco, é isso? E pra deletar não é só remover a linha 57(marcado na imagem)
Enfim como me desfaço desses dados que não quero mais?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Luciano, como o modelo Categoria está dentro do modelo Produto via Inline, o que o django presume é que eles contém um relacionamento. Portanto, deletar a linha 57 resultaria no erro informado na foto.

Você pode apagar a class CategoriaInline, retirar a citação do ProdutoAdmin e aí apagar a chave estrangeira no model.

Eu não sei se vc conseguiria apagar os dados do banco usando apenas o django. Acredito que nesse caso é mais fácil usar o cliente do SQL q vc estiver usando pra deletar as informações que não tem mais necessidade.

Comment: Carlos, fiz o que vc sugeriu, deletei no pgAdmin. E resolveu uma parte. outro erro continuou e acabei descobrindo que essa opção: Inline não se aplica no que eu estava fazendo, só consegui perceber agora. Mas deu tudo certo, só agradeço!!